How to update cabinets that have a beveled edge
I'm wanting to update my kitchen cabinets to shaker-style using MDF trim around the existing cabinet doors. However, the cabinets have beveled edges. Is it still possible to do this? Can I fill the gaps with wood filler?

Photos of what you are trying to do might help.

Your best bet is making new doors and drawer fronts.  If your handy with wood, you can get an inexpensive router table or if you have a table saw, you can cut pieces for shaker style doors with dado blades.

There are places online that sell cabinet doors and drawers to order, they can be finished too. If you wish to do a  budget fix, table saw off the edges square and use different hinges that have a different overlay.
